# How can I use recursive with the my tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue, I have 2 tables

```
table_a {
    id,
    name
}

table_a_b{
    id_a,
    id_b
}
```

this is an exemple of data

```
table_a

id | name
1  | test

table_a_b

id_a | id_b
1    |  5
10   |  5
10   |  20
34   |  20
34   |  2
18   |  2
```

I have to use the `id 1` in `table_a` to go in `table_a_b` thinks to this id. After that i have to use the `id_b` of the row `5` to access to the `id_a = 10` and with this id I have to go to `id_b = 20` to use it for an other line ?

and i have to do this a lot of times (till there is no corrsponding data)

someone have any idea how to do that ?

**UPDATE**

```
WITH CTE ([id_a], [id_b], [Level])
AS (
    SELECT
        a.id_a, a.id_b, 0 AS [Level]
    FROM
        table_a_b A
    WHERE
        [id_a] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        A.[id_a] , A.[id_b], CTE.Level + 1 AS [Level]
    FROM
        table_a_b A
        INNER JOIN CTE ON A.id_a= CTE.id_a
        WHERE Level < 80
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

For the moment it only show the first line a 81 times

**UPDATE**

This is the final output is

```
  id_a   | lvl
    1    |  0
    10   |  1
    34   |  2
    18   |  3
```

I want the id_a and the lvl. But to do that i have to do a loop

1. search the id_a to get the id_b
2. search with the id_b an other id_a

and repeat that.

Comment: Hint: the word you are looking for is "recursive". Searching for "hierarchical data" might also help.

Comment: I was hoping that you would [search for that term yourself](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=sql+recursive&ia=web) rather than just editing the title.

Comment: @IMSoP I search I just update my title and the code cause there is close request for the ticket. I can update to show u what I actually try.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what I'm looking at now. Are you saying you solved the problem? Or that you have some code, but it doesn't do what you want? What *does* it do? See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/157957

Comment: What should be the final output?

Comment: @IMSoP no problem :) Nope my code doesn't resolve my issue I have to continue to search to achieve my issue

Comment: @RaseenaAbdul I update my post if u want to see

Comment: Your current code has a simple typo, that's why it's joining the row to itself: `A.id_a= CTE.id_a` should be `A.id_a= CTE.id_b` or `A.id_b= CTE.id_a`

Comment: @IMSoP it can't be `A.id_a= CTE.id_b` or `A.id_b= CTE.id_a` because `id_a` and `id_b` are not the same things

i search `id_a` to get `id_b` but `id_b` is an other column and to get `id_a` again it's an other row but I have to use `id_b` to get `id_a`. I guess it's a little bit difficult to understand how it works sorry and my english is not very good

Comment: I have 3 suggestions: 1) Give those columns clearer names; it's very easy to get in a muddle with generic names like "a" and "b". 2) Spend some time reading some explanations of recursive CTEs; they are confusing, so don't expect to understand them instantly. 3) Step back, come up with an [mcve] that represents your data well, and re-write the question explaining as clearly as you can given what you've learned so far. Don't worry about leaving a trail of updates in the question's text, there's a [history of all the edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66551542/revisions) if anyone cares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every recursion step is a two way operation:

```
iteration   id_a -> id_b   id_b -> id_a
---------   ------------   ------------
1         =    1 ->  5   &    5 -> 10
2         =   10 -> 20   &   20 -> 34
3         =   34 ->  2   &    2 -> 18
```

That is why the recursive part of the CTE should also contain two joins.

**Sample data**

```
create table table_a
(
  id int,
  name nvarchar(10)
);

insert into table_a (id, name) values
(1, 'test');

create table table_a_b
(
  id_a int,
  id_b int
);

insert into table_a_b (id_a, id_b) values
(1 , 5 ),
(10, 5 ),
(10, 20),
(34, 20),
(34, 2 ),
(18, 2 );
```

**Solution**

```
with rcte as
(
  select null    as abFrom,
         null    as abStep1,
         0       as abStep2,
         ab.id_a as abTo,
         0       as lvl
  from table_a_b ab
  join table_a a
    on a.id = ab.id_a
union all
  select ab1.id_a,
         ab1.id_b,
         ab2.id_b,
         ab2.id_a,
         lvl + 1
  from rcte rc
  join table_a_b ab1
    on  ab1.id_a = rc.abTo
    and ab1.id_b <> rc.abStep2
  join table_a_b ab2
    on  ab2.id_b = ab1.id_b
    and ab2.id_a <> rc.abTo
)
select r.abFrom,
       r.abStep1,
       r.abStep2,
       r.abTo,
       r.lvl
from rcte r;
```

**Result**

```
abFrom   abStep1  abStep2  |  abTo     lvl
-------  -------  -------  |  -------  -------
null     null     0        |  1        0
1        5        5        |  10       1
10       20       20       |  34       2
34       2        2        |  18       3
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=02099746b1c418e49b88e7be05fa5b49) to see things in action.